# Picture size decreases by 6 bytes after image through sockets

Tags: php, python, image, sockets

I'm trying to send a picture taken from a camera by sockets to a PHP server. Everything works fine except, when the image is delivered to the server side it's always -(5 to 10) bytes the original picture, making the image damaged and unacceptable.

Sender Side :

[image: this is the sender side which is 54,546 bytes]

Receiver Side :

[image]

For the sender side I'm using python  :

```
enter code here

import socket   
import datetime
import json
import base64 , urllib
from cam import *


captureImage()

facechop('test_image.png')

image ='test_image.png'


print "----------------------------------------------"

try:
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('X.X.X.X', 20001))

client_socket.send(image)



        #print strng
    #client_socket.send(l)
    #l = img.read(1024)

print "Data send Successfully"

#print client_socket.recv(1024)
client_socket.close()


except Exception as e:
print("ERROR: "+str(e))
```

and for the receiver side I'm using PHP to save the image to the server :

```
function checkMessageRecieved()
{
    foreach ($this->changed as $key => $socket) {
        $buffer = null;

        while(socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 1024, MSG_WAITALL)) {


            $theData .=$buffer;

        }

    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/../photos/public/". uniqid() .".png",$theData);


        echo "The file has recieved successfully";

    }
}
```

Comment: `Size` is the actual size of the file in bytes.

`size on disk` is the actual amount of space being take up on the disk. the disk is broken down into tracks and sectors.

Comment: I'll bet that you're missing precisely 6 `\x0A` bytes, and that something in your code needs to be fed a 'binary-safe' flag.

Comment: @Sammitch do you have any suggestion to fix the problem ?